# Call to undefined function gmp_import() in php

Tags: php, cryptography, gmp

I'm tying to implement [this](https://github.com/loostro/cryptomute) cryptography library in PHP. I tried running the example code given in the readme. I am getting this error in [DataConverter.php](https://github.com/loostro/cryptomute/blob/master/lib/Cryptomute/DataConverter.php):

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function gmp_import() in
> /home/user/cryptomute/lib/Cryptomute/DataConverter.php on line 165

I have the GMP extension enabled in php. I am running the code from the terminal. The other gmp functions don't seem to have problem since they are before the gmp_import() in the code. Can anyone please help me running the code?

Answer (score 1):

**[gmp_import](http://php.net/gmp_import)**

> (PHP 5 >= 5.6.1, PHP 7)

Bet you don't have that. Many other `gmp` functions run fine on earlier versions of PHP

Comment: Thank you! I upgraded to version 5.6.26 and gmp_import() works, but now I'm having the same problem with gmp_cmp(). This is very strange!

Comment: That one looks like it should work just fine `PHP 4 >= 4.0.4, PHP 5, PHP 7)`

Comment: Exactly. It should, but it isn't.

Comment: haaaaaaaaaaaaaalp